# Whitespace on side of web page

Tags: html, css

In code below I have set the width of page to `980px` and there appears some whitespace at right side, which disappears on setting `body` width to `1050px`. My screen resolution is 1366x768, I have read that most websites have `950px` to `980px` width and most websites like facebook entirely fit into my screen then why my `980px` is having whitspace at right side.

```css
body {
  width: 980px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
}
.one {
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.two {
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
}
.three {
  height: 200px;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="one">this is first block
  </div>
  <div class="two">the content changes it's position on zooming in
  </div>
  <div class="three">Is there any way to keep it as it is with a scroll bar
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the margin of html or body to 0?

Like:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a6uL4f57/)

*EDIT:* The white space is a margin that is set as default for html, so if you want your page to be "borderless", you simply need to set the margin of html (and to be safe that of body, you never now what different browsers will do) to 0.

Answer (score 1):

try unsetting width see what happens. I don't set page width on anypage I make and It works fine. now If I have a box a table a shadowbox ect ill set dimensions for that but I dont ever designate a page width. Maybe just comment it out refresh see what happen.

Comment: http://cssdeck.com/labs/x0qkkv6a   with your method on zooming header and body fall short of content,, on zooming and scrolling to right to will see header ends first of content and body(where body background is gray)will now have whitespace on scrolling right